# How to codesign with an Extended Validation Code Signing Certificate on Mac

Tags: macos, codesign, signtool

I am trying to codesign with hardware token on Mac.

According to this

https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base/detail/Signing-with-an-Extended-Validation-Code-Signing-Certificate/kA03l000000c4TX

> 1. Plug your Token into your computer.
> 2. Open SafeNet Tools
> 3. Open Command Prompt
> 4. Input the following command below: signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a
>    "Path_to_the_file_you_wish_to_sign "
> 5. SafeNet should open with a prompt asking users to input your password for the token.
> 6. After successfully inputting the password, your application will be successfully signed. At this point, you’re all set to start
>    distributing your application to your end-users! For those wishing to
>    check that the application was successfully signed, please see the
>    steps below.

It worked fine on my Windows.

Now, how do I codesign on Mac?

I am trying like this

```
$ codesign -s "Your Company, Inc." "/path/to/yourApp.app"
```

But it says "Warninig: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer xxxx"

Answer (score 1):

To get past this problem, I installed the two EV Code Signing root certificates from here:  https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-Intermediate-Certificates

Unfortunately I then get prompted for a PIN and as yet I have no idea what the PIN is.

Answer (score 0):

[apple developer forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682140)

About an EV code signing certificate by sectigo.com,

> It’s not that it’s not supported per se, just that it doesn’t buy you very much.

> and it is recommended to obtain an apple-issued code signing certificate.

I am not sure what it really means, but it seems that I should obtain an apple-issued code signing certificate.